# Embed manifest to exe failing with argument invalid

Tags: windows, manifest, exe, administrator

I want to add a manifest to .exe file so it stops asking users to run as administrator in Windows 7.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.aneef.net/2009/06/29/request-uac-elevation-for-net-application-managed-code/) which seems to do exactly what I want to accomplish except I get this error when I do the same and I cannot find a solution for it:

```
mt.exe : general error c101008d: Failed to write the updated manifest to the resource of file "C:\install.exe". The parameter is incorrect.
```

this is the command I used:

```
mt.exe –manifest C:\install.exe.manifest -outputresource:C:\install.exe;1
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It's all on the local drive, right?  I've seen this error when the output is a shared drive.

Comment: I actually solved this problem and I will post the solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem, it was actually a syntax issue:

```
mt.exe –manifest "C:\install.exe.manifest" -outputresource:"C:\install.exe;#1"
```

There is an even better solution is to edit the .exe directly using visual studio.